# Why is "object" underlined in red in my Firebase code?

Tags: firebase, android-studio, kotlin

I am trying to get into Kotlin using Firebase. The examples I have viewed want me to add the following code: `object: ChildEventListener`. In `Java` this was `new ChildEventListener`. But the `object` part is marked red with the message: `object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member`. Not sure what it means or how to solve it. Here's the

```
db = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().reference

db!!.child("cookies").addChildEventListener(object: ChildEventListener {

          //CODE HERE TO GET DATA
         }
     })
```

I had a similar problem when creating a `Button` which I solved by completely removing the argument list (the parenthesis and its content) but it doesn't work here. This is obviously a simple problem with a simple solution, but I'm just starting out and feel a bit confused by the syntax. Any help with this would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[ChildEventListener](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/ChildEventListener) is an abstract class so you should implement its abstract members:

> object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member

```
db!!.child("cookies").addChildEventListener(object: ChildEventListener {

          override fun onCancelled(error: DatabaseError) { }
          //etc
     }
 })
```

Comment: Ah, I see, I had to implement all of its functions (even though I don't use all of them?). The red underline disappeared. Thank you so much for taking the time helping me out! :)

Comment: That's right. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/abstract.html